# Meaning of $S^{I}$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a measurable space $(S, \Sigma) $ and an index set I.
What does it mean by $S^I$. Can someone explain with the help of an example? I am studying stochastic processes and found this in the definition of Path space.

Comment: In set theory, the notation $A^B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets are typically functions from $B$ to $A$, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of functions from the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ to the real numbers, i.e. each number in $1, \ldots, n$ gets associated to a real number.

Comment: It should be the product space $S^I$ (the set of functions $f\colon I\to S$) with the product $\Sigma$-algebra, generated by sets of the form $[i_0,U]=\left\{f\in I:f(i_0)\in U\right\}$, where $i_0\in I$ and $U\in\Sigma$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I didn't get the idea where you told $R^n$ is a set of functions. t is actually the cartesian product of real numbers right?

Comment: Yes but this is another way to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is the space (or simply the set) of maps $I\to S$. Another way of saying the same thing in the case $I$ is countable is the set of sequences of elements of $S$ indexed by $I$, since any map $I\to S$ determines a sequence given by the images and any sequence indexed by $I$ determines the image of a map $I\to S$.

Comment: "Sequence" might not be the ideal term here since $I$ could be uncountable in monstrous ways, though I'm not sure what would be better.. But good answer nonetheless!

Comment: @CameronWilliams you are definitely right. I just like to think this as "generalized" sequences.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest language possible: $S^I$ is the set of all functions from $I$ to $S$.

This avoids the possibly confusing term "space".